# Automatically change value in sql database based on a given date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Is it possible to change value in sql automatically. For an example it´s a rent-a-car database and a customer wants to make a reservation for a car for, let´s say, 15th of july (now it's 4th). when i run my C# program and click on a button to reserve that car it writes in the database in the RentalDate Column July 15th(future date).Now in the Availability Column (is the car available) it should stay True until that date (15th) comes and then should be automatically changed to False. Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: yes but keep logic out of database so the next guy that picks up your code won't puke

Comment: If the `Availability` is a derived value, that is, it is calculated from other values, it should not be stored in the database itself. Otherwise there is potential for the `RentalDate` and `Availability` to disagree, in which case how would you know which one to believe?

Comment: the Availability is bit value-if the car is in RentedCars table it´s 0, otherwise it´s 1.

Comment: Yes, but you are asking if it can be automatically kept up to date. I'm saying it would be better to check the reservation dates and determine if it is available, _because you already have the required information in your database_. How would you set the `Availability` boolean anyway? By checking the `RentalDate`? If so, why store it, just check `RentalDate` every time you want to know.

Comment: yes that would be a way, but i cant change it now. because in my program i´m not suppose to see the cars which are not available(currently rented), so with the boolean i can easily do that.if the car has it´s boolean set to 0, i can´t see it in my program as a rental option.So i check its status  with availability.If i press the Reserve button in my program and pick the date, when that date comes its availability should be set to 0. When the customer returns the car, i click the button and it´s available again

Comment: @user3613744 your database structure looks seriously flawed. how do you handle in your database two rental requests for the same car? if i rent car A from july 4th to july 9th and you book car A from july 12th to july 18th how do you store these information in your database? if you use a single flag to say 'car not available' how do you handle the gap between 9th and 12th july where car A is available?

Comment: Give extracts of database schema and c# code for how you are reading the availability and how you would update *some* value in the database. Right now your question and counter-arguments are too vague for us to know what would suit you.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider a different design where you keep a booking table and a car table. Then if you reserve a car you can write a row to the booking table with the time span. You can then check against this table to see if the car is available for an arbitrary requested time span.

Comment: that is actually a great idea, but the problem is that i can´t change it now :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [SQL Agent Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) that executes a stored procedure to perform the update on a given schedule, i.e. every day at  midnight.

Stored procedure code would contain something like this to compare the RentalDate with today's date to perform the update:

```
UPDATE RentalsTable
SET Availability = 0 -- False as a bit
WHERE RentalDate = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) -- takes date portion of GETDATE()
```

Sample script to create a job to run a stored procedure would look something like this:

```
--Add a job
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'MY UPDATE JOB';

--Add a job step named process step. This step runs the stored procedure
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'MY UPDATE JOB',
    @step_name = N'process step',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = N'EXEC [YOUR_STORED_PROC_TO_PERFORM_UPDATE]'

--Schedule the job at a specified date and time
exec sp_add_jobschedule @job_name = N'MY UPDATE JOB',
@name = 'MySchedule',
@freq_type=1,
@active_start_date = '2014-07-03',
@active_start_time = '00:00:00'

-- Add the job to the SQL Server Server
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name =  N'MY UPDATE JOB',
    @server_name = N'[SERVER NAME]'
```

Alternately, you can use Management Studio and a wizard to create scheduled jobs.

The above script was adapted from the [following site](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3052/simple-way-to-create-a-sql-server-job-using-tsql/), which also has a step by step guide to setting up job via management studio.

Further Reading: [How to: Create a SQL Server Agent Job (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: The spec off what? The question in the post you mean?

Comment: If the job runs at midnight, how much more immediate would you want it?