# Creating EVENTS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, events

I want to execute a query at a specific time. In MySQL we use events for that, example is as follows:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

Please let me know how to do the same in SQL Server. Thanks.

PS : Sorry if its a repeated question. I tried searching for some time but didn't get it in SQL Server

Comment: If this is to be on a set schedule, you would schedule a Job using [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx).  In the job, you can have it execute a stored procedure or simply run your `UPDATE` script

Comment: Take a look at **[this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24564195/57475)** on another question, which details how to create an agent job to perform time based operations.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But, this seems to be a very tiresome approach to create events. Hope Microsoft comes up with simpler ways to do the same. Any one of you can write that as an answer so that I can "tick" that answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use Sql server agent for this task and you can schedule there. Its easy way.
2. Another one is "waitfor time" check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187331.aspx
   (and you need to create a trigger with while loop logic and there wait for time is useful)
3. Another one create a bat file and schedule that in windows scheduler (if you are using sql sever express edition)